# Creating a stretchable body for a character rig

Tags: animation, rigging

Struggling with the bird rig, I've set up the basic skeleton and IK for the legs. Now I'd like to create a bendy bone structure for the body, allowing it to squash and stretch during jumps. However, I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. I've attempted to create a bendy bone for the body, but it seems that in order for it to stretch, the bones controlling the bendy bone need to be detached from the other bones. This disrupts the skeletal hierarchy and doesn't work as intended.

Has anyone figured out a way to make the body stretch without breaking the skeleton, and without affecting other rig controls? (For example, the eyes, beak, and glasses should maintain a constant size regardless of how the body stretches)

[blender file with rigged bird, if needed](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10PWiubErlYXi0TzO7r6CJJiiQSp3AjDn)

[image: how it looks]

Comment: *"This disrupts the skeletal hierarchy and doesn't work as intended."* - what does not work? A bendy bone requires 2 control bones as handles and a *Stretch To* bone constraint. Can't you integrate the control bones in the hierarchy?